# Salesforce Platform API Versions 7.0 through 30.0 Retirement

Tags: apex, rest, soap

I received an email from Salesforce for the withdrawal of two features (Salesforce Platform API Versions 7.0 through 30.0 Retirement
):

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_US&id=000354473&type=1&mode=1&utm_source=techcomms&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=eol
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_US&id=000354473&type=1&mode=1&utm_source=techcomms&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=eol

I'm not using SOAP or Rest calls in my Apex code

Could you confirm that the API version of the Apex code also needs to be greater than 30 (Or does that have nothing to do with it?)

What should I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the same page link you put in your question (by the way, it is the same link twice)

> This retirement does **not** include Custom Apex REST & SOAP Web Services, **Apex Classes, Apex Triggers**, or Visualforce Pages.

So I'd say no, apex code does not need to be greater than 30 ;)

You might want to have a look at all integrations that use the standard APIs, such as integrations (eg. old dataloader), plugins (eg. Excel plugin), other tools (eg. SOQL Xplorer, Force.com Explorer, etc)

If you have visualforce pages / controllers that are using the standard API, you might want to update the endpoint they use to increase the API version (callouts)

Since they use the soap interface, my guess is that it will also affect if you use buttons / javascript that are using the libraries connection.js / apex.js

Comment: Thanks Sergio Alcocer ! I did not see that ! I see also : "This retirement affects all API-enabled org editions and applies to both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience." So i have not to verify anything ?

Answer (score 4):

To check if your org will be impacted, you can use the following [sfdx-hardis command](https://hardisgroupcom.github.io/sfdx-hardis/hardis/org/diagnose/legacyapi/):

`sfdx hardis:org:diagnose:legacyapi`

A detailed explanation is also available in [this article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/handle-salesforce-api-versions-deprecation-like-a-pro-335065f52238)